# Jetpack Compose BottomSheetScaffold: Smooth closing

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I'm using Jetpack Compose with the BottomSheetScaffold. To be able to show and hide the bottom sheet from both within and outside the composable, I used a `showBottomSheet: MutableState<Boolean>` variable. The peek height within the composable is then determined like this:

```
val baseBottomSheetPeekHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(60.dp) }
val bottomSheetPeekHeight = if (showBottomSheet.value) baseBottomSheetPeekHeight else 0.dp
```

Later, in the `BottomSheetScaffold`, I use the variable like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
  ...
  sheetPeekHeight = bottomSheetPeekHeight,
  ...
)
```

(Full reproducer project here: https://github.com/dbrgn/compose-repro)

This generally works as intended, I can set `showBottomSheet.value` to `false` to hide the bottom sheet. However, the hiding looks janky, because not all sub-composables are hidden at the same time.

[image: GIF animation of the issue]

It's a bit hard to see in the animation above due to the GIF conversion, but when closing the bottom sheet peek pane, the other content (below it) is visible for a short moment, before the bottom sheet disappears.

Is there a way to avoid this janky hiding behavior? Or even better, is there a way to smoothly animate the hiding of the pane?

Comment: why calling collapse/expand on the state is not enough? this is designed way of sheet showing/hiding.

Comment: When I call "collapse", the bottom sheet is still being shown (sheetPeekHeight), or am I missing something? The old View-based bottom sheet had three states: Expanded, collapsed and hidden. The Compose-based bottom sheet only has two states: Expanded and collapsed.

Comment: `BottomSheetScaffold` provides persistent bottom sheet, it doesn't meant to be hidden. Consider using `ModalBottomSheetLayout` instead

Comment: @PhilipDukhov the modal bottom sheet layout won't work for me, because it does not allow users to access content out of the bottom sheet's scope (which is a feature I need).

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?  I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case for Smooth closing BottomSheetScaffold I used to: `scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.animateTo(Collapsed, tween(duration))`
-- (when `duration` is any Int you want).
The same for Expanding:
`scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.animateTo(Expanded, tween(duration))`

If you look at the source code of collapse() or expand() function, you will see there just calling animateTo(Expanded) and animateTo(Collapsed). You can customize animateTo() as you wish.

See [animateTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/SwipeableState#animateTo(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.animation.core.AnimationSpec)) documentation.

Comment: `animateTo` is not any longer public since m3